# How install Intl, GMP and BCMath PHP extensions?

Tags: gmp, intl, bcmath

Centos 6.8 Final

Php 7.0.16

Directadmin control panel

yum install php-gmp

yum install php-bcmath

yum install php-intl

result is: No package xxx available.

Thank you.

Comment: You use a panel altered distro, not a centos distro... (check exclude directives in yum configuration)

Answer (score 1):

BCmath is already preinstalled with PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/bc.requirements.php

For other libs try to define repository where yum would search artifacts and then install the extension. For example,

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl
```

Another alter way is described there https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/
Take a look at the `php70w-common` package which includes **gmp**, and further just install `php70w-bcmath` and `php70w-intl`. Don't forget to enable all packages inside php.ini.